# What are the reasons that Allah gave the Torah and Gospel before the guidance of the Quran?

Tags: quran, allah, christianity

I know that Surah Al-E-Imran 3 states:

> He has revealed to you the Book with the truth,
>   confirming what has been before it, and has sent down the Torah and
>   the Injil.

Thus, we know that it is Allah who sent the words of the Torah and Gospel before the Quran.

What are the reasons that Allah first gave these books? I am confused as to why the Bible implies that the text is His final message, with words like:

> If any man shall add unto these things, God shall add unto him the
>   plagues that are written in this book: And if any man shall take away
>   from the words of the book of this prophecy, God shall take away his
>   part out of the Book of Life, and out of the holy city, and from the
>   things which are written in this book --Revelation 22:18-19

I would like to understand the reason that Allah gave us messages like these, knowing that he would later give us the rest of His guidance. Why did Allah give us these other texts from before the Quran, which include such messages that lead people astray?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I'm pretty sure that one will find a similar question with the correct keywords/tags on the site. At the moment I Failed to find it.

Comment: The book of Revelations is neither Torah nor Gospel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allaah supported the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) with physical miracles, with which he challenged his people. Among the most important of these were the splitting of the moon and the Night Journey to Bayt al-Maqdis (Jerusalem). They were unable to match these miracles, and so they were a decisive, divine testimony to the truth of his Prophethood (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him).

Allaah supported him with miracles and evidence for people of reason and understanding, the greatest of which was the Qur’aan. This was the greatest sign, which contains in its pages miracles of both style and content, which all of mankind cannot match or imitate, even if they gather together for that purpose. This is clear from the statements of the most eloquent of the Arabs, who were completely unable to match it. The Qur’aan was – and centuries later still is, praise be to Allaah – an eternal miracle as is evident in its brilliant style, its information about the Unseen, its fulfilment of the promises of Allaah, the superiority of its laws, and the fact that its rulings are appropriate for every time and place – in addition to the fact that it has such a moving impact on people’s hearts.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2114/evidence-for-the-truth-of-the-prophethood-of-muhammad

From this we understand that every prophet had a miracle, this is our propeht (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam miracle)

As for the mods please do not change my answer, my answer was written at a time of jahl, and deen is not through qiyas. Please and fear Allah.

Answer (score 0):

**Allah in Torah** gives prophecy of Coming of Prophet Muhammad.  Allah inform believer by giving information in Previous scripture. So that people know the coming Prophet. Before Prophet Muhammad came, Allah send each *nation* messengers. After sending each nation messengers Allah had plan to unite believers Using Glorious Quran to make one Ummah (community). If Allah had send Quran before than there would be no need of Bible or Torah because Quran is only guidance for *whole Mankind*. And it is already preserved and Allah has taken responsibility to preserved. So there would have been no need to send Bible, Torah later as Torah and Bible were Particularly for Specific nation for specially Israel.
Although unbeliever corrupted the Books, we still can find the words of Allah in Torah even in Hebrew. And Allah challenges no one can change his words , we can bring his words Back.
https://youtu.be/ezMkJgllzvo

Answer (score 0):

You quoted Revelation 22 as follows:

> If any man shall add unto these things, God shall add unto him the plagues that are written in **this book**: And if any man shall take away from the words of **the book of this prophecy**, God shall take away his part out of the Book of Life, and out of the holy city, and from the things which are written in **this book**

and said you were confused as to "why the Bible implies that the text is His final message."

The New Testament was not written as one book but is a collection of 27 books. Thus, the phrases "this book" or "the book of this prophecy" in the passage you quoted refer only to the book of Revelation, not any other part of the biblical text or the Bible as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

Allah gave each nation a messenger (quran 10:47)-(quran 14:4).. And Allah name are hidden by all the follower of the books. Example is in Torah as well in Hinduism.. So Allah kept giving the message to each nations. It was the will of Allah . Allah wanted people to corrupt so that Allah test other by one another. And Allah wanted Quran to preserved that is why Allah send it last
here is two religions done for You to verify, " Has Allah wanted he would made u all one people, but intent to test u so vie with another in performing good works"(Quran 5:48)

“ALLAH created heavens and earth in 6 days”.- (Quran-10:3)

In the First Chapter of Bible , God finishes the creation in 6 days. According Hebrew Bible, Etymology ,ancient Hebrew root, Theology ,Lexicon Early Bible commenteries, Biblical Cyclopedia ,Encyclopedia Palestinian targum, Palestinian talmud all these sources proves ALLAH is the only true word in Hebrew for God. Allah alone created Heavens and Earth. Note- The word Elohim/God is now lost in original Hebrew and Only preserved in arabic says all non Muslim sources in the video. There is no other name when God finish his creation in 6 day, than the True word which is ALLAH. There is no Yahweh/no Jesus /no Elohim. That is why we say There is no God but "Allah". https://youtu.be/ezMkJgllzvo

Say, "Have you considered that which you invoke besides Allah ? Show me what they have created of the earth; or did they have partnership in [creation of] the heavens? Bring me a scripture [revealed] before this or a [remaining] trace of knowledge, if you should be truthful." – (Quran 46:4)

Answer (score -2):

Salam
From what I know, everything is not misleading. I think everything is the same as teaching to believe in Allah, Prophet, Angel, Kitab (bible), and qodo qodar from Allah. It's just that the way of delivery is not as perfect as the Prophet. And even the delivery of the prophet is not wrong, different human interpretations. And in all kitab like torah and gospel states there is no god but Allah, and Muhammad SAW is the Prophet.